# Spring Boot JOOQ sql dialect not picked up from application.properties

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jooq

Background: i am hosting the trial version of jooq 3.9.1 (proprietary eg oracle db compatible) in my nexus repository - all the dependencies in my pom relating to jooq point to that.

i have this line in my application.properties

```
jooq.sql-dialect=ORACLE
```

but when i inspect the injected dslContext the dialect is set to "DEFAULT" and not ORACLE as expected/desired.

I am currently getting round it by autowiring the datasource rather than the dslcontext and then setting the sql dialect (as shown below) - but wondering why autowiring the dslcontext directly doesnt work as expected

```
@Autowired
private DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSource;



public static final SQLDialect sqlDialect = SQLDialect.ORACLE;

public DSLContext getDSL(){
    return DSL.using(dataSource, sqlDialect);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the configuration should be `jooq.sql-dialect`? The manual references a configuration `spring.jooq.sql-dialect` instead: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-jooq

Comment: For the record, there might be some room for improvement in Spring Boot itself. Just in case, [I've registered an issue here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8794)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lukas' comment [Spring Boot JOOQ sql dialect not picked up from application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102316/spring-boot-jooq-sql-dialect-not-picked-up-from-application-properties#comment73406648_43102316) is correct.

Here is an example how to do it and test:

Inside application.properties

```
spring.jooq.sql-dialect = Postgres
```

And tested with an integration test `ConfigIT`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JdbcTest
@ImportAutoConfiguration(JooqAutoConfiguration.class)
public class ConfigIT {

    @Autowired
    private DSLContext dSLContext;

    @Test
    public void dialectShouldBePickedUp() {
        assertThat(dSLContext.configuration().dialect(), is(SQLDialect.POSTGRES));
    }
}
```

You'll find the working and tested example in the repositories of http://springbootbuch.de here: https://github.com/springbootbuch/database_examples

What's important ist to choose the right, case sensitive name. In my example, it's `Postgres`, in your example it should be `Oracle` and you must use the right property. Sadly, those names vary across different tool sets. For jOOQ you'll find the constants in `org.jooq.SQLDialect`

Answer (score 2):

[Spring Boot by default uses the `org.jooq` dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-jooq/pom.xml#L34), which is the Maven `groupId` for the jOOQ Open Source Edition:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However, the [Oracle `SQLDialect`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html#ORACLE) is contained only in the commercial distributions of jOOQ, which are available under different `groupId` (and not from Maven Central but from [here (trial)](https://www.jooq.org/download/) and [here (express, professional, enterprise edition)](https://www.jooq.org/download/versions)):

```xml
<groupId>org.jooq.pro</groupId>        <!-- for commercial editions -->
<groupId>org.jooq.pro-java-6</groupId> <!-- for commercial editions with Java 6 support -->
<groupId>org.jooq.trial</groupId>      <!-- for the free trial edition -->
```

The distributions are almost completely binary compatible, so you should be able to simply replace the `<groupId>` in your own pom.xml for Spring Boot to work with jOOQ and Oracle.

Comment: thanks for the super quick response.  I am using the trial version (3.9.1) hosted in my nexus repository.  I am currently getting round this by autowiring the datasource rather than the dslContext and setting the sqldialect to give me the correct dialect dslContext

Comment: @JohnWilson: Oh, sure, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: whats does? the original issue still stands?

Comment: Your workaround makes perfect sense. Have you tried my answer? Does it work?

Comment: If I wasnt using the commercial versions of jooq then i wouldnt be able to set the oracle dialect in my workaround cos as you say it is not available i n the o/s addition, so to answer your question-  no your answer doesnt work, spring boot is not picking up the jooq.sql-dialect=ORACLE i n application.properties even when using commercial (trial) version of jooq

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. I'll leave my answer as it is here in case someone else does have this problem. Will further investigate.