# Jooq Multiset - SQL shows the word multiset thorwing syntax error - Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jooq

I am using Jooq version 3.16.6 with Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.6.6 and (PostgreSQL) 14.1

The issue i am having is with multiset , the non multiset query using the old join method works fine . However when using multiset and examining the sql i can see the word multiset actually in the sql query hence it thorws a syntax error

```java
var result = 
dslContext.select(USERS.FIRST_NAME,USER_LEVELS.USER_LEVEL_NAME)
        .from(USERS)
        .join(USER_LEVELS)
    .on(USERS.USER_LEVEL_ID.eq(USER_LEVELS.USER_LEVEL_ID))
        .where(USERS.USERNAME.eq("email@email.com"))
        .fetch();
```

The above is the standard join method works fine

The below is the multiset version

```
var result =
      dslContext.select(USERS.FIRST_NAME,
            multiset(select(USER_LEVELS.USER_LEVEL_NAME)
                .from(USER_LEVELS)
                .where(USER_LEVELS.USER_LEVEL_ID.eq(USERS.USER_LEVEL_ID)))
)
            .from(USERS)
            .where(USERS.USERNAME.eq("email@email.com"))
            .getSQL();
```

I am using the getSQL to see the sql it is running which comes out as below

```sql
select "public"."users"."first_name", 
   multiset(select "public"."user_levels"."user_level_name" 
       from "public"."user_levels" where "public"."user_levels"."user_level_id" = "public"."users"."user_level_id") from "public"."users" where "public"."users"."username" = ?
```

The issue is obviously the multiset being in the sql which causes a syntax error.

I am at a loss as to why this is , unless its some setting for my postgres (which i don't think)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't configured your [`SQLDialect`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SQLDialect.html) correctly, e.g.

```
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=Postgres
```

See also: [Spring Boot JOOQ sql dialect not picked up from application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43102316/521799)

Comment: N.B: It's supposed to work out of the box, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11464, but apparently, it didn't in your case. Perhaps a different type of misconfiguration, or you're not actually using PostgreSQL, or a bug in Spring Boot?

Comment: Thanks the issue was indeed the dialect i should have spotted that but i just thought it was something with my query or the version of Jooq. 

As i am using two different databases and creating two different DSL contexts in my config the change in the properties file didn't work 

I had to actually do         

config.set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);

Where i am setting up the DSL contexts to get it working. It may have been the fact i am using the configs that it did not pick up dialect automatically. 

Without confusing the issue the problem was indeed the dialect